# OpenGL ES 2.0 equivalent of glOrtho()?

Tags: iphone-sdk-3.0, opengl-es, projection-matrix

In my iphone app, I need to project 3d scene into the 2D coordinates of the screen for some calculations. My objects go through various rotations, translations and scaling. So I figured I need to multiply the vertices with ModelView matrix first, then I need to multiply it with the Orthogonal projection matrix.

First of all am on the right track?

I have the Model View Matrix, but need the projection matrix. Is there a glOrtho() equivalent in ES 2.0?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
mat4 projectionMatrix = mat4( 2.0/768.0, 0.0, 0.0, -1.0,
                              0.0, 2.0/1024.0, 0.0, -1.0,
                              0.0, 0.0, -1.0, 0.0,
                              0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);                        

gl_Position = position;
gl_Position *= rotationMatrix;
gl_Position.x -= translateX;
gl_Position.y -= translateY;
gl_Position *= projectionMatrix;
```

For a fixed resolution (1024x768 in my case for iPad) I used this matrix and everything works like charm :)
Here is complete description what values you need to put in your matrix: [glOrtho.html](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/documentation/opengles1_0/html/glOrtho.html)

Answer (score 3):

The [manual page](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) for `glOrtho()` describes the equivalent operations, so as long as you have the matrix handy should be able re-implement it.